# How can we export datatable to PDF using iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, itext, export-to-pdf

How can we export datatable to PDF using iTextSharp in C#?

```
public void ExportToPdf(DataTable dt)
   {      
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("c://sample.pdf", FileMode.Create));
    document.Open();
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(dt.Columns.Count);
    PdfPRow row = null;
    float[] widths = new float[] { 2f, 2f, 2f, 2f };
    table.SetWidths(widths);
    table.WidthPercentage = 100;
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Products"));
    cell.Colspan = dt.Columns.Count; 
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is sample code. Please check this.

```
public void ExportToPdf(DataTable dt)
   {      
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("c://sample.pdf", FileMode.Create));
    document.Open();
            iTextSharp.text.Font font5 = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 5);

    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(dt.Columns.Count);
    PdfPRow row = null;
    float[] widths = new float[] { 4f, 4f, 4f, 4f };

    table.SetWidths(widths);

    table.WidthPercentage = 100;
    int iCol = 0;
    string colname = "";
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Products"));

    cell.Colspan = dt.Columns.Count;

    foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
    {

        table.AddCell(new Phrase(c.ColumnName, font5));
    }

    foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
    {
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[0].ToString(), font5));
            table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[1].ToString(), font5));
            table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[2].ToString(), font5));
            table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[3].ToString(), font5));
        }          
    }  document.Add(table);
        document.Close();
}
```

Comment: This is the better solution if you go for speed. The other answer by @vakeel requires you to first convert the data to HTML and you start creating the PDF only when the HTML is fully created. For large data sets, this seriously slow your application down. Moreover, the other answer uses `HTMLWorker`, a class that has been abandoned.

Comment: Is this solution valid for iText7?

Answer (score 4):

This is more general. It will work with any DataTable

```
public void createPDF(DataTable dataTable, string destinationPath)
{
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(destinationPath, FileMode.Create));
    document.Open();

    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(dataTable.Columns.Count);
    table.WidthPercentage = 100;

    //Set columns names in the pdf file
    for(int k = 0; k < dataTable.Columns.Count; k++)
    {
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(dataTable.Columns[k].ColumnName));

        cell.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER;
        cell.VerticalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER;
        cell.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(51, 102, 102);

        table.AddCell(cell);
    }

    //Add values of DataTable in pdf file
    for(int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < dataTable.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(dataTable.Rows[i][j].ToString()));

            //Align the cell in the center
            cell.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER;
            cell.VerticalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER;

            table.AddCell(cell);
        }
    }

    document.Add(table);
    document.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all import  iTextSharp library in ASP.Net.

**HTML Markup**

The HTML Markup consists of a Button to generate PDF

```
<asp:Button Text="Generate Invoice" OnClick="GenerateInvoicePDF" runat="server" />
```

**C#**

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser;

protected void GenerateInvoicePDF(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Dummy data for Invoice (Bill).
    string companyName = "ASPSnippets";
    int orderNo = 2303;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[5] {
                            new DataColumn("ProductId", typeof(string)),
                            new DataColumn("Product", typeof(string)),
                            new DataColumn("Price", typeof(int)),
                            new DataColumn("Quantity", typeof(int)),
                            new DataColumn("Total", typeof(int))});
    dt.Rows.Add(101, "Sun Glasses", 200, 5, 1000);
    dt.Rows.Add(102, "Jeans", 400, 2, 800);
    dt.Rows.Add(103, "Trousers", 300, 3, 900);
    dt.Rows.Add(104, "Shirts", 550, 2, 1100);

    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            //Generate Invoice (Bill) Header.
            sb.Append("<table width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2'>");
            sb.Append("<tr><td align='center' style='background-color: #18B5F0' colspan = '2'><b>Order Sheet</b></td></tr>");
            sb.Append("<tr><td colspan = '2'></td></tr>");
            sb.Append("<tr><td><b>Order No: </b>");
            sb.Append(orderNo);
            sb.Append("</td><td align = 'right'><b>Date: </b>");
            sb.Append(DateTime.Now);
            sb.Append(" </td></tr>");
            sb.Append("<tr><td colspan = '2'><b>Company Name: </b>");
            sb.Append(companyName);
            sb.Append("</td></tr>");
            sb.Append("</table>");
            sb.Append("<br />");

            //Generate Invoice (Bill) Items Grid.
            sb.Append("<table border = '1'>");
            sb.Append("<tr>");
            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                sb.Append("<th style = 'background-color: #D20B0C;color:#ffffff'>");
                sb.Append(column.ColumnName);
                sb.Append("</th>");
            }
            sb.Append("</tr>");
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                sb.Append("<tr>");
                foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                {
                    sb.Append("<td>");
                    sb.Append(row[column]);
                    sb.Append("</td>");
                }
                sb.Append("</tr>");
            }
            sb.Append("<tr><td align = 'right' colspan = '");
            sb.Append(dt.Columns.Count - 1);
            sb.Append("'>Total</td>");
            sb.Append("<td>");
            sb.Append(dt.Compute("sum(Total)", ""));
            sb.Append("</td>");
            sb.Append("</tr></table>");

            //Export HTML String as PDF.
            StringReader sr = new StringReader(sb.ToString());
            Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
            HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
            pdfDoc.Open();
            htmlparser.Parse(sr);
            pdfDoc.Close();
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Invoice_" + orderNo + ".pdf");
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.Write(pdfDoc);
            Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

reference by :http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Generate-Invoice-Bill-Receipt-PDF-from-database-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: This answer uses `HTMLWorker`. `HTMLWorker` has been abandoned in favor of [XMLWorker](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker). If your dataset is small, creating an HTML and then converting it to PDF using [XML Worker](http://itextpdf.com/product/xml_worker) might be acceptable. If you have a large dataset, this approach will have a serious impact on your memory and CPU use. In that case, the answer by @Nakala is the better solution.